# Semantic UI calendar, drop down menu overflow full width

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I made a calendar where I can click on each day.
When I put my mouse on the last column div, it overflows the screen width.

```
<div class="menu"><a href="#" class="item">EEEEEEE</a></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c0oh7kby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply transformation on last `<td>`, to pull tooltip to the left:

```
td.ui:last-child .ui.simple.dropdown:hover > .menu {
    transform: translate(calc(-100% + 16px), 0);
}
```

Or put it to the right:

```
td.ui:last-child .ui.simple.dropdown:hover > .menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0oh7kby/1/)

### Edit

Before that count all menu items, that overflows viewport:

```
$('.ui .menu').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.width() + $this.parent().position().left > $(window).width()) {
    $this.addClass('transformed');
  }
});
```

And then apply needed css:

```
.ui.simple.dropdown:hover > .menu.transformed {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0oh7kby/5/)

However it doesn't compensate if tooltip is overflowing in both sides. for that You can check twice:

```
$('.ui .menu').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.width() + $this.parent().position().left > $(window).width()) {
    $this.addClass('transformed');
    if ($this.parent().position().left - $this.width() < 0) {
      $this.addClass('center');
    }
  }
});
```

And apply transformation:

```
.ui.simple.dropdown:hover > .menu.transformed.center {
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0oh7kby/7/)

Comment: yes, it works, but it not exactly what i want. when i change text for example to 100 characters i should change transformation for several columns

Comment: i am looking something what check div menu is overflow full width, if yes then transformation